# How to show "No Result Found" If no data found - Angular Material Datatable Filter

Tags: angular, filter, angular-material

I want to show "no result found" in angular material datatable when filter.
Here is my sample code [Sample Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-datatable-multi-column-filter-28m7sa)

This is how I want:
[image]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your datasource there is a property called `filteredData`. `filteredData` is updated with the latest data list after applying your filter. so, you can just simply check the length of `dataSource.filteredData` and determine what you want to show or hide.

I have created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tglsgt). you can have a look on this.

Comment: Hi @sadid, Can we  show "no result found" inside the table? Now it is outside <table>

Comment: I have modified the above stackblitz a bit [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tglsgt-i2taij?file=app%2Ftable-filtering-example.html) and now it looks like the message is inside the table.

Comment: @SamuelKavinLoganathan yes, of course we can. then don't hide the table when there is no data in the list and do some css trick as Fabian Küng already created a stackblitz . hope it helps. Actually I just demonstrated the main workaround how we can show no data based on filtered data. 

If this answer helps, feel free to accept the answer

Comment: @SamuelKavinLoganathan Have updated answer, without extra CSS and boolean variable

Comment: Thanks you SadidKhan & fabian

Answer (score 4):

You can check the length of `dataSource.filteredData` list and then display No Content Found message inside the table:

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [formControl]="nameFilter" placeholder="Filter 1 (working sample)">
</mat-form-field>

<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. 
      <div>
      <mat-form-field>
  <input matInput class="form-field" [formControl]="positionFilter" placeholder="Postion Filter">
</mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name 
       <div>
      <mat-form-field>
  <input matInput class="form-field" [formControl]="nameFilter" placeholder="Name Filter">
</mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
  </ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="isDataAvailable">
   <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef colspan="6">
      No Data found
   </mat-footer-cell>
</ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
<mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="['isDataAvailable']" [ngClass]="{'hide':!(dataSource.filteredData!=null && dataSource.filteredData.length==0)}">
   </mat-footer-row>
</table>
```

[`Updated_StackBlitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-datatable-multi-column-filter-aelffw)

Comment: The StackBlitz lacks the css styling for the hide class.
But it got me in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: is there anyway make row selection disable when we have no records found?